# How to get data from custom table without using object manager

Tags: magento2, database, extensions

I want to insert data in custom table "outofstockproductnotification". But before insert data, I want to check if some data like email id and product id is already exist or not in my custom table. I saved it by using this code.

filepath : app/code/Chirag/Stockproduct/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

<?php  if (!$_product->isAvailable()): ?>
<div id="emailnotificationstock" class="">
    <label for="notification-container-1183">
            Subscribe to back in stock notification </label>
    <div class="notification-container" id="notification-container-1183">
        <form method="post" name="emailnotification" id="emailnotification" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('stockproduct/index/save'); ?>" >
            <div class="input-fields fieldset">
                <input name="guest_email" class="input-text amxnotif-guest-email" id="amxnotif-guest-email-1183" size="50" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" placeholder="Insert your email">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="createddate" value="<?php echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary">
                    <span>Submit</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

file path : app/code/Chirag/Stockproduct/Controller/Index/save.php

```
namespace Chirag\Stockproduct\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Chirag\Stockproduct\Model\TestFactory;
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Stockproduct
     */
    protected $_test;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TestFactory $test
    ) {
        $this->_test = $test;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('guest_email');
    $product = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
    $createddate = $this->getRequest()->getParam('createddate');
    //check weather user already register for same product.
    //if not exist data than submit data
    $test = $this->_test->create();
    $test->setEmailid($email);
    $test->setProductid($product);
    $test->setCreatedAt($createddate);
    if($test->save()){
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('We will notify you when product is in stock!'));
    }else{
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Error!! Data was not saved.'));
    }
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    return $resultRedirect;
    //if data exist than display approprate message 
    //$this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('You already registerd for this product.'));
    }
}
```

In save.php, I want to check if there is emailid and productid is already exist or not in custom table "outofstockproductnotification". Here i put code of two files only. I think you can understand from these. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I put this code in save.php

```
<?php

namespace Chirag\Stockproduct\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Chirag\Stockproduct\Model\TestFactory;
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Stockproduct
     */
    protected $_test;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TestFactory $test
    ) {
        $this->_test = $test;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('guest_email');
        $product = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
        $createddate = $this->getRequest()->getParam('createddate');
        //check weather user already register for same product.
        //if not exist data than submit data
        $test = $this->_test->create();
        $collection = $test->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('emailid', array('eq' => $email))
                                            ->addFieldToFilter('productid',array('eq' => $product))
                                            ->addFieldToFilter('emailstatus',array('eq' => 1));
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->Count());exit;
        if ($collection->Count() == 0){
            $test->setEmailid($email);
            $test->setProductid($product);
            $test->setCreatedAt($createddate);
            if($test->save()){
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('We will notify you when product is in stock!'));
            }else{
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Error!! Data was not saved.'));
            }
        }
        else{
            //if data exist than display approprate message 
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This email ID already registerd for this product.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
?>
```

Using `$test->getCollection()` data will come without object manager.